# Calculating difference in values in one table based on another table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables.  MarketAction has the value I am finding for called 'B1', which will match to the 'Ticks' field in the TickTable.

(The MarketAction table is 25 million rows and the TickTable is 300 rows)

The tick table looks like this:

```
TickID    Ticks    MinorMagnet
140       2.80     1
141       2.82     0
142       2.84     0
143       2.86     1
144       2.88     0
145       2.90     0
146       2.92     0
147       2.94     0
```

I need to find 'TickDiff', and insert 'B1' and 'TickDiff' into a new temporary table.

If we look up the TickID for 'B1' from the TickTable, I need it to find the difference in the TickID's between the B1 TickID and the nearest `MinorMagnet = 1` TickID value (the first higher (or zero), and the first lower (or zero)).

This works for the high:

```
WITH T1 AS
(
    SELECT TOP 20 *, 
            144 - TickID AS TickDiff
    FROM TickTable
    WHERE MinorMagnet = 1
    ORDER BY ABS( Ticks - 2.88 )
)
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM T1
WHERE TickDiff >= 0
```

If I wanted the lower one I can modify for:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *, ABS(TickDiff)
FROM T1
WHERE TickDiff <= 0
```

But obviously works because I am explicitly stating the values from MarketAction.  B1 = 2.88 and 144 is the TickID of B1.

I have tried all sorts of Joins and other things...  Can't get my head around it...

How do I make it find the 'TickDiff' for each B1 value in MarketAction?

Comment: Please edit your question and add sample data *into the question*.  You can format it as a table using four spaces at the beginning of each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then maybe this query might be what you want:

```
select tickid, ticks, minormagnet, min(abs(tickdiff)) tickdiff 
from (
    select ma.TickID, t.Ticks, t.MinorMagnet, tickdiff = t.TickID - oa.TickID 
    from MarketAction ma
    join ticktable t on ma.TickID = t.TickID
    outer apply (
       select top 2 TickID 
       from ticktable 
       where MinorMagnet = 1 
       order by abs(t.Ticks-Ticks) 
    ) oa
) x
group by tickid, ticks, minormagnet;
```

Comment: Amazing thank you so much.  The ma.TickID didn't exist because the TickID is derived from 'Ticks' in the TickTable but I created a temp table with that information in and solved it that way.  I'm sure there is a more elegant solution but I'm not advanced enough yet to solve for the ma.TickID in the same query.